# What is best and simple way to get view height except navigation bar?

Tags: iphone

I want to get height of view except navigation bar. I used below method so far. Is there better way?   And isn't it dangerous to hardcode height of navigation bar as 44.0?

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
viewHeight = screenRect.size.height - 44.0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want combine for ? It's simple and the best way.

If you do that often in your code you can make some macro like

`#define kViewHeight CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; viewHeight = screenRect.size.height - 44.0;`

or something like that.

Comment: I don't want to use 44.0. How do I get navigation bar height?

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height is right.